# React Project returns White Page (Portfolio project)

Tags: reactjs, git, deployment, build, production

I have built my first React project (Portfolio webpage) and when trying to upload it to Github pages it gives a blank page.

You can check in the following link the git repository for this project: https://github.com/vasco-alex-sousa/personal-portfolio

Thank you in advance for your help.

When running npm run deploy (after running npm run build and npm install gh-pages --save-dev) it gives the warning "ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/vascosousa/Desktop/3d_portfolio/build'"

[image]

Comment: add `base` key in vite.config.js defineConfig function and set its value to your repo name

Comment: And also in package.json replace `"homepage": "https://vasco-alex-sousa.github.io/"` with    `"homepage": "https://vasco-alex-sousa.github.io/<your-repo-name>"` and `"deploy": "gh-pages -d build"` with `"deploy": "gh-pages -d dist"`

Answer (score 0):

Collectively Follow Below Steps:

1. Add base key in vite.config.js defineConfig function and set its value to your repo name

`export default defineConfig({ base:"<your-repo-name>" plugins: [react()], })`

2. In `package.json`
   `"homepage": "https://vasco-alex-sousa.github.io/<your-repo-name>"` and
   `"deploy": "gh-pages -d dist",`